# jquery reverse array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have the following snippet which returns some youtube id's.
Now I want to reverse the output (because now it is the last first)

```
if (options.slideshow) {
var links = [];
var $lis = holder.parents('#yt_holder').find('li');
var $as = $lis.children('a');
for(var count = $lis.length-1, i = count; i >= 0; i--){
    links.push(youtubeid($as[i].href));
    }
 slideshow = '&playlist=' + links + '';
 alert(slideshow);
}
```

I tried .reverse() but some items seems to be missing then

```
links.reverse().push(youtubeid($as[i].href));
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Ceasar

Comment: Instead of moving backwards through the array of `$as` (decrementing towards `0`) and then reversing the array, why not go *forwards* through the array of `$as`, by incrementing towards `i<$lis.length`?

Comment: Where did you call `links.reverse().push(youtubeid($as[i].href));`? In your for loop? You should just call `reverse` once.

Answer (score 14):

You should reverse the list *after* you've accumulated it:

```
for ( ... ) {
    ...
}
links = links.reverse();
```

but it would be better to just put the elements into the array in the right order in the first place.

Comment: This also works.

What is the best solution
Jason's or yours ?

And do you know how to skip the first one in the array ?

Thanks

Comment: @ceasar to remove the first element - `var first = links.shift();`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the videos in the reverse order, so instead of this

```
for(var count = $lis.length-1, i = count; i >= 0; i--){
    links.push(youtubeid($as[i].href));
    }
```

Do this

```
for(var i = 0, count = $lis.length; i < count; i++){
    links.push(youtubeid($as[i].href));
    }
```

Comment: He jason. That works :-) Now how can I remove only the first one in the array

Thanks for your help

Comment: links.shift(); is the answer to my own question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you after reversing the links array ,you have to assign it to other array and hence it will work.

```
var slideshow = [];
slideshow = links.reverse();
```